# django run selenium test

Tags: django, selenium

I have a problem to run selenium tests with separate django command. Default "test" command looks into "tests" folder and runs unittests ok. Problem is, i want to make folder "seleniumtests" and place there test files to run them with command "test_selenium". And i want this command to do the same as default django "test" but in another dir.
The tests.py with selenium:

```
from django_liveserver.testcases import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver


class MySeleniumTests(LiveServerTestCase):
#    fixtures = ['test-data.json']

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.selenium = WebDriver()
    super(MySeleniumTests, cls).setUpClass()

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(cls):
    super(MySeleniumTests, cls).tearDownClass()
    cls.selenium.quit()

def test_admin(self):
    self.selenium.get(self.live_server_url +'/admin/')
    self.assertIn("Django", self.selenium.title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial on how to put your tests into folders: http://www.pioverpi.net/2010/03/10/organizing-django-tests-into-folders/

in general:

```
from [Project Name].[App Name].tests.[filename] import *  
from [Project Name].[App Name].seleniumtests.[selenium] import *  

#starts the test suite  
__test__= {  
           'your_django_tests': [filename],
            'selenium': [selenium],
           }
```

Comment: i have already folder tests with __init__ but i want to set another admin command to run selenium testing from folder seleniumtests with its own __init__.py.